# Whats the anchor point on a view when using the translateX and translateY in Android

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a view inside. The view overtimes changes it's position so my question is I'm running into an issue where say the top and left coordinates are say max height and max width and the view is displayed partially on screen while the rest is cut off .

So my question is **when translating the view is the view adjusting relative to the center pixel of the view or the bottom left top left bottom right or top right?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of translateX and translateY it doesn't matter. No matter what anchor point you would use, the result would be the same. Scale and rotation however rely on the anchor point (or pivot) defined by setPivotX/PivotY.

Comment: The problem i have is when I translateX for my view(its a textview)  it overflows and is cut off when it reaches with width of the screen I want move it back and have the last letter touch the edge